# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Hey so I'm getting this weird error

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

I cannot find a solution anyway on the internet, any advice please?

Here it is:

```
Route::post('api/avatarDetails/{avId}', 'API\APIController@doAvatarDetails');
Route::get('api/avatarDetails', function() {
  return Redirect::to('/')->with('failure', 'You lack the ability to do that young one.');
});
```

There you go @Alexy

```
Route::get('/', function() {
  return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to use when you get this error message?

Comment: `api/avatarDetails` trying to post avId to it and return json data from my jsonrpc server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this route, but you still trying to redirect to it:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
});
```

If you have one, run `php artisan route:clear` command which will clear all old route cache.

Comment: So do you have route for '/'? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: Try to clear routes cache with `php artisan route:clear` commands. If this will not help, please run `php artisan route:list` and post the list in your question.